# CreateProcess + CREATE_SUSPENDED flag equivalent in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, process

I'm wondering if there's a way to start process suspended?

Similar to CreateProcess + CREATE_SUSPENDED in windows:

```
CreateProcessA(
        NULL, 
        CmdLine, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        FALSE, 
        CREATE_SUSPENDED,
        NULL, 
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\", 
        &si, 
        &pi);
```

ptrace seems to support PTRACE_ATTACH only, there's no way to start a process and suspend it directly, any ideas?

**EDIT**

I need to be able to catch process like this,

```
int main()
{
   exit(0);
}
```

So the shell approach will not work, as the process quits really fast.

Comment: `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` option seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to take process details as an input in a process, fork, and in child before exec-ing the process, send stop signal to self.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

main()
{
    int pid;
    //Note: Replace argv_list with corresponding binary and arguments
    //Can also get these values as command line argument from main(argc, argv)
    char *argv_list[] = {"/usr/bin/ls","-lrt", "/", NULL};

    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        printf("Child Executing\n");
        //Send STOP signal to self to suspend
        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
        //Sleep for stop signal handler to suspend current process
        sleep(1);
        //This line should start to execute only after CONT signal is sent.
        execv(argv_list[0],argv_list);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Child PID:%d, Parent continuing\n", pid);
    }

    printf("\n***Main - Exiting\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You say "this line should start to execute only after CONT signal is sent" but provide no details. How is the CONT signal sent? Who sends it? I am trying to port an application that uses CreateProcessW to start another process suspended, displays a message box, and then continue the new process when the OK button is pressed. Can this be used to duplicate that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one to one comparison for shell but here is which is similar in terms of spinning a process and then suspending it and then starting it again.

```
###to start a process:
#!/bin/bash
function_some_proc() {
echo "hi"
# if this is too fast you can always use "sleep" to add some time
}

function_some_proc &
FOO_PID=$!
echo "--"
echo $FOO_PID
echo "--"

###then to suspend 

kill -STOP <PID>

#to resume 

kill -CONT <PID>
```

Comment: Updated question

Comment: you can actually get PID as soon as you execute your job, I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The article [Creating suspended processes](https://knight.sc/malware/2019/01/06/creating-suspended-processes.html) provides an excellent answer to this question. Note that there are problems with this article. Scott Knight, the author of the article, obviously did not bother to confirm that his code examples will actually compile. The parent function refers to a mysterious pid variable.

A complete working example can be found in my [StartSuspended](https://svn.sullivanandkey.com/SnKOpen/cpp/StartSuspended/trunk/) project. My StartSuspended project compiles on Microsoft Windows and GNU/Linux. See [StartSuspendedPlatformPosix.cpp](https://svn.sullivanandkey.com/SnKOpen/cpp/StartSuspended/trunk/StartSuspendedPlatformPosix.cpp) for the GNU/Linux implementation.

I used the following functions in the GNU/Linux implementation.

- [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)
- [execvp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)
- [waitpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)
- [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)